# How to enable SlimScroll when reach max height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slimscroll

I am using slim scroll for a div. I want show the slim scroll only when the content of the div reach the max-height of the div. Is there any way i can achieve this?

```
$('#main-table-body').slimScroll({
            height: '66px',
            width: '100%',
            size: '10px',
            alwaysVisible: true,
            distance: '7%'
        });
```

Like this I have added slim scroll to the div.Div have a static height 66px. And content are getting added to the div dynamically. When content reach the max space in the div only slim scroll need to be showing. Otherwise don't need.

Comment: yes, definatly there is a way, first you can show your work here. what you have done?

Comment: It might help you https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll/issues/70

Comment: Edited the question and added some more info